# Set the video width and height to 100% in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How can I remove this black area and set the video width and height as 100%?
Here is what I have tried so far

```
<iframe src="https://watch.wave.video/60073f3d46e0fb00017557d4"  
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with iframe tag but with your link as it is not returning you directly the video.

If you have access to that link you can update it to return a video with 100% width and height. Since you are using plyr try to include this style:

```
.plyr {
  height: 100%;
  width :100%;
}
```

Comment: That's a third party video. https://watch.wave.video/60073f3d46e0fb00017557d4

Comment: Than if you know the aspect ratio you might be able to fix it otherwise there is no option to make it 100% width and height because you can not edit content inside iframe